# How to init simple pod * as array in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I personaly have a problem with float, tried:

```
auto p = new float*({$X, $Y, $Z});
```

`$X, $Y, $Z` local variables. What do I do wrong?

Comment: something wrong with your code. What do you expect from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is the same as the old pre-C++11 standard, mixed with the new uniform initialization syntax:

```
auto p = new float[3]{X, Y, Z};
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative that avoids explicit dynamic allocation and deallocation use a [`std::vector<float>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with the initializer syntax:

```
std::vector<float> p{ X, Y, Z};
```

If you need access to the underlying array you can access it via [`std::vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).